# How to use a variable from jinja2 in a for block

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, jinja2

I am trying use a Jinja2 with variable inside of a for block as a dictionary parameter.

```
{% for x in dict_one %}
    {% with id=x.id %}
        <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{x.id}}</th>
        <td>
        {% for a, b in dict_two.id.items %}
            Key: {{a}} Value {{b}}
        {% endfor %}
         </td>
        </tr>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this scenario my page doesn't display any data. In the case when I will hardcode this line changing id in 11 (a value that display in my table from x.id) it works.

```
{% for a, b in dict_two.11.items %}
```

The solution should make possible to use the with-variable inside of accessing a dictionary's item.

Comment: show code of views.py

Comment: It's not really big deal, dict_one is a QuerySet, and every object has the field id and the dict_two is like:  {11: {'Item_ABC': 2}, 12: {'another_item': 23}}. I am interested in displaying all fields of queryset and then the fields who match the id from the second dictionary ( the one with items)

Comment: @learner123 Please try to handle your nested for loops and with-statement inside your view.py

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the second dictionary to my first dictionary from view and then call like this. I still didn't manage to include a jinja variable in a for-block.

`{% for a, b in dict_one.dict_two.items %}`

Answer (score -1):

```
{% for x in dict_one %}
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{x.id}}</th>
    <td>
    {% for a, b in x.items %}
        Key: {{a}} Value {{b}}
    {% endfor %}
     </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for because you x is an object from the dict_one, but I have to access items from dict_one corresponding to my x.id